# Scrollmagic doesnt work - How could i fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollmagic

I am working on a project and tried to use scrollmagic. It does not work and I don't know why. I tried many things.

I tried different names / different files and libaries.

It's a little bit of code, so here's a jsfiddle with everything!

Whole Code is in the Fiddle ->>>
[The JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9u8bwLcr/)

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
        $('nav').addClass("sticky");
    } else {
        $('nav').removeClass("sticky");
    }
});

$(window).ready(function() {
    $('.unhid').on('click', function(e) {
        $('.hidden').addClass("showmenu");
        $('.bar').addClass("switch");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('.hidth').on('click', function(e) {
        $('.hidden').removeClass("showmenu");
        $('.bar').removeClass("switch");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('.hidden li').on('click', function(e) {
      setTimeout(function() {
```

Comment: Please explain "it does not work".

Comment: clicking on one nav link simply doesnt scroll down (scrollmagic should do the trick but it does not work)